# why does this regex work outside of a javascript function but not inside of it?

Tags: javascript, regex, email, validation, undefined

Okay so I'm kind of new to regexps in general, let alone in Javascript.

I am trying to work on a form validation project and I found a site where they have a list of useful sample regexps for various things [here](http://ntt.cc/2008/05/10/over-10-useful-javascript-regular-expression-functions-to-improve-your-web-applications-efficiency.html) which has a few for email validation, which is what I'm attempting at the moment.

Anyway, following this example for form validation on w3schools I was able to get it working properly using their example and the regexp works outside of the javascript function, but for some reason when I call it inside the function it returns a value of undefined.

Here's my code:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>formzz validate-jons</title>
      <script type="text/javascript">
        pattern = new RegExp("^[0-9a-zA-Z]+@[0-9a-zA-z]+[\.]{1}[0-9a-zA-Z]+[\.]?[0-9a-zA-Z]+$");

        function valid8email(field, txt)
        {
          with(field)
          {
            //at_pos = value.indexOf('@');
            //dot_pos = value.lastIndexOf('.');

            if(!pattern.test(value)) //at_pos < 1 || (dot_pos - at_pos) < 2)
            {
              alert(txt);
              return false;
            }
            else
            {
              return true;
            }
          }
        }

        function valid8(form)
        {
          with(form)
          {
            if(valid8email(email, "you must enter an email address") == false)
            {
              email.focus();
              return false;
            }
          }
        }
      </script>
    </head>
    <body>
      <form action="#" method="POST" onsubmit="return valid8(this)">

        Email: <input type="text" name="email" size="30" />
        <input type="submit" value="clicky-click" />

    </form>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      alert(pattern.test(""));
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Okay... so the alert in the script tags inside the body works just fine.

I've done numerous tests inside the javascript function itself and checked various things:

- the type of 'value' is String
- the function returns 'undefined' when called inside the javascript
- the regex itself works fine as it will return true when the proper formatting is entered in the script tags below

So what could the issue be? I am confused.

Comment: Outside of a dog, a book is a man’s best friend; inside of a dog, it’s too dark to read anyway.

Comment: `with` is _evil_.  **Do not use it**.

Comment: That's a terrible regex; stop using that site!

Comment: +1 for the question, haven't seen anyone hit issues with the `pattern` attribute yet :)

Comment: @Pointy: *which* site? I just saw w3schools.com learned him that [horrible kind of form validation](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_form_validation.asp). Can't that site be thrown off the internet?

Comment: That site with the list of "useful sample regexps". It really looks totally misguided.

Comment: To specify *why* that's a terrible regex: here's an address like one I use which won't get matched: `myemail+yoursite@example.com`.  Or `myemail@some.subdomain.example.com`.  Or many, many others.  Regular expressions are the wrong tool for validating email addresses; [this regex/monstrosity](http://www.ex-parrot.com/pdw/Mail-RFC822-Address.html) for validating them, which *still* isn't perfectly correct (though pretty much is), illustrates why.

Comment: @Antal – I agree that regex is not the best tool for email address validation, but the one featured [here](http://fightingforalostcause.net/misc/2006/compare-email-regex.php) seems to work reasonably well (also using JavaScript's RegEx).

Answer (score 8):

The problem is that `pattern` refers to `field.pattern` ([an HTML5 attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Element/input)) because you're using it inside the `with()`, and that's a string, not your regex.  If you called it something else like `pattern1`, [it would work fine](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/GELkX/1/).

That being said, don't use `with` in the first place, and you won't have these issues :)

---

The non-`with` version looks like this:

```
var pattern = new RegExp("^[0-9a-zA-Z]+@[0-9a-zA-z]+[\.]{1}[0-9a-zA-Z]+[\.]?[0-9a-zA-Z]+$");

function valid8email(field, txt) {
    if (!pattern.test(field.value))
    {
        alert(txt);
        return false;
    }
    else {
        return true;
    }
}

function valid8(form) {
    if (valid8email(form.email, "you must enter an email address") == false) {
        form.email.focus();
        return false;
    }
}
```

[You can test it out here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/GELkX/).

Comment: Why do you use `new RegExp` instead of a literal?

Comment: @Marcel - I didn't change it from the OP's code...my objecting was to point out what the issue was and why (the HTML5 attribute combined with the `with` block), not re-write the code :)